# moving an appended input after clicked span.

Tags: jquery

Im working on a text editor simulation that appends an input to a div, and extracts its values to create spans, here is the initial click() function:

```
var $cursorStart= $("#cursor-start");

$("#main-edit").click( function() {
var cursorExists = $("#cursor").length;
if (!cursorExists){
   $cursorStart.append("<input type='text' id = 'cursor' />");
   $("#cursor").markCursor();

}
   if (cursorExists){
    $("#cursor").focus();

}

});
```

When I start typing, spans are inserted before the input:

```
jQuery.fn.enterText = function(e){
var $cursor = $("#cursor");
if( $cursor.val() && e.keyCode != 32  ){
    var character = $("#cursor").val();
    $cursor.val("");
    character = character.split("").join("</span><span class='text'>");
    $("<span class = 'text'>"+character+"</span>").insertBefore($cursor);



}
```

What I want to know now is, how can I move the input (cursor) around (basically be inserted after a clicked span).

```
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```

clicking near a and b would result in an input after "a". These are spans that are dynamically added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the new span, you can bind a new click event to it:

```
$("<span class = 'text'>"+character+"</span>").insertBefore($cursor);

$cursor.prev().click(function(){
  $(this).after($cursor);
});
```

You could also use jQuery's `.live()` function, but this is generally not a good solution because it is so expensive.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work^ it seems that cursor.prev() is not found?...I tried $(#cursor).prev() also

Comment: actually got it to work :p. would siblings() be better to define the objects?

Comment: you don't want to use siblings() because that would refer to all sibling elements. you only want to bind the click event to the newly created span. here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/shAzR/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery caret plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caret) for x-browser compatible functions for managing the caret position or selection in a textbox or textarea. This will allow you to move the "input cursor" around, as you described it :-)

---

*This is assuming "What I want to know now is, how can I move the input (cursor) around" was your question, which I'm not 100% clear on.*

Comment: im actually simulating a cursor in a div box.